# Using map function of javascript, how to return data from an array in the desired format?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a state called `testers` which is of type an array. After updating the state of my testers array, I can see the following data printed out to the console:
Testers

```
0: { _id: {…}, username: "John Smith" }
1: { _id: {…}, username: "Tester_1" }
2: { _id: {…}, username: "John Doe" }
```

and I am using react-multi-select (https://github.com/kenshoo/react-multi-select) which uses the following format to display data from an array:

```
items: [
  { id: 0, label: "item 1" },
  { id: 2, label: "item 2" },
  { id: 3, label: "item 3" },
  { id: 4, label: "item 4" }
]
```

How can I use my testers array to return the data in the same format using the id and username?

```
testers: [
  { _id: 1, username: "John Smith" },
  { _id: 2, username: "Tester_1" },
  { _id: 3, username: "John Doe" }
]
```

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: `let arr = testers.map((item, idx) => { return { _id: idx, username: item.username} });` ?

Comment: Thank you so much @Jack!

Answer (score -1):

You can simply create new property and delete old one.

```
var a = [
  { _id: 1, username: "John Smith" },
  { _id: 2, username: "Tester_1" },
  { _id: 3, username: "John Doe" }
];
a.map((e)=>{
    e['id'] = e._id;
    e['label'] = e.username;
    delete e._id;
    delete e.username;
});

console.log(a); // desired output
```

Comment: You could, but you really should not. Create a new object instead.